# How to edit video like this?

Tags: premiere, after-effects, final-cut-pro-x

How they manage to dissolve text only and not themselves??

In some videos text even go over there hands but still texts dissolves and they remains intact..

Example is in this video please go through it 1st is at 4 seconds then at 1:30.

Comment: They probably just masked off the part of the screen with the text on it, and dissolved it. I didn't see the part you describe with the text dissolving over her hand, I was too distracted by her incorrectly calling a scalar a "constant".

Answer (score 3):

Sit behind a sheet of glass, write, flip video, key dissolve.

Comment: That's a pretty definitive answer :)

Comment: @tomh - Thanks. There seems to be some doubters (over a dozen thus far) whom wait for a better answer, I'd like to see what they come up with.

Comment: this is so funny ^^ 
Sometimes it's just a super simple solution but nowadays people think it is all edited digital :D